# How do I add a new Subdocument if it's not exist already, then push another subdocument under it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a Schema named user on mongoose, and that schema has lastExams property as below:

```
lastExams: [{
       lecture:  {
           type: String,
           required: true
       },
       exams: [{
        examID: {type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: Exam, required: true},
        resultID: {type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: Result, required: true},
        date: {type: Date, required: true},
        result: {}
    }]}]
```

With this, I want to keep the last 10 exams user have taken for each lecture they have. So after each exam, I want to check if the corresponding 'lastExams.lecture' subdocument already exists, if so, push the result that lastExams.$.exams array. Else, upsert that subdocument with first element of the exams array.

for example, thats an user document without any exams on it;

```
  user: {
    name: { firstName: '***', lastName: '***' },
      email: '****@****.***',
      photo: 'https://****.jpg',
      role: 0,
      status: true,
      program: {
        _id: 6017b829c878b5bf117dfb92,
        dID: '***',
        eID: '****',
        pID: '****',
        programName: '****',
        __v: 0
      },
      lectures: [
        {
        some data
        }
      ],
      currentExams: [
         some data
      ],
      lastExams: []
    }}
```

If user sends an exam data for math-1 lecture, since there is no exam with that lecture name, I need to upsert that document to get user document to become as below;

```
user: {
  name: {
    firstName: '***',
    lastName: '***'
  },
  email: '****@****.***',
  photo: 'https://****.jpg',
  role: 0,
  status: true,
  program: {
    _id: 6017 b829c878b5bf117dfb92,
    dID: '***',
    eID: '****',
    pID: '****',
    programName: '****',
    __v: 0
  },
  lectures: [{
    some data
  }],
  currentExams: [
    some data
  ],
  lastExams: [{
    lecture: 'math-1',
    exams: [ 
      examID: 601 ba71e62c3d45a4f10f080,
      resultID: '602c09b2148214693694b16c',
      date: 2021 - 02 - 16 T18: 06: 42.559 Z,
      result: {
        corrects: 11,
        wrongs: 9,
        empties: 0,
        net: 8.75,
        score: 43.75,
        qLite: [
         'some question objects' 
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}
}
```

I can do that like this;

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate({email: result.user}, {$addToSet: {'lastExams': {
                       lecture: result.lecture,
                       exams: [{
                        examID: doc.examID, // btw, idk why, these id's saving to database as arrays
                        resultID: doc.id,
                        date: doc.createdAt,
                        result: doc.results
                      }]
                     }}})
```

But since this adds new subdoc with same lecture value each time. I am having to check if there is a subdoc with that lecture value first manually. if not so, run the above code, else, to push just exam data to that lectures subdoc, I am using below code;

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({email: result.user, 'lastExams.lecture': result.lecture }, {$addToSet: {'lastExams.$.exams': {
   examID: doc.examID,
   resultID: doc.id,
   date: doc.createdAt,
   result: doc.results
  }}})
```

So, I am having to make User.find() query first to see if that lecture is already there, and pop an item if it's exams.lengt is 10. then deciding to what kind of User.findOneAndUpdate() to use.

Do you think there is any way to make this proccess in a single query? Without going to database 2-3 times for each exam save?

I know it's too long, but i couldn't put it straight with my poor english. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods:

1. Like you already did, multiple queries.
   In the first query, you have to check if the subdocument exists, if it does, update it in the second query, else create subdocument with first item in the second query.
2. Using $out in an aggregation pipeline
   If multiple round trips is only the issue, checkout $out aggregation pipeline method, which allows to write aggregation output to a collection. In there, you can first match you document, check if the subdocument exists, using $filter followed by $cond. Once you have the data ready, use $out to write it back to the collection.

NB: Aggregation pipeline is expensive operation than findOneAndUpdate IMO, so make sure you test the average latency for both 2 query method and single aggregation method and decide which is faster in your case.

PS: Sorry for not providing an example, I simply don't know it very well to create a working example for you. You can refer to the mongoDB docs for details.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Also, there is a Jira ticket discussion going on for this specific use case in MongoDB. Hoping some simple solution will be implemented in MongoDB in the upcoming versions